# I seem to have a phantom follower that won't let me enlist a follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had Faendal as a follower, and he disappeared somewhere along the way. Found him back at his house. I asked him to follow, but he says I already have a follower. I killed the dragon, but Lydia says the same thing. Is there any way to reset it back to no follower? I really don't want to start over.

Comment: Have you tried waiting (in-game waiting) for any extended periods of time to see if anyone shows up?

Comment: You don't happen to know approximately where you lost Faendal? It is possible that he is still fighting against some enemies there. (the combat won't progress if you are too far away so he is stuck there). Also it wouldn't be unheard of Followers getting stuck in the Broken Oar Grotto

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this glitch but I think the only way is to force/cheat him to make you your follower or go back to a previous save.

And anyway the only benefit of having a follower is a little extra damage and increased carry weight (putting stuff on follower) and anyway you should only carry the crucial stuff for your build.